# Use VBA to select predefined multlevel list style in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to determine the right syntax for selecting my predefined multilevel list before typing text without the VBA redefining every time.

I am still learning VBA and know the limits of recording a macro. Apparently when I try to apply my predefined multilevel list, the recorder sets all of the attributes of the list.

All I am trying to do is select my predefined multilevel list titled "MyList", type "Text", go to next line, type "Text" again. My VBA is over 100 lines because it defines each level of list which I am sure is unnecessary if I am already using a saved list.

This is not my exact multilevel list but one of the built-in ones.

```html
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
        .NumberFormat = "%2)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 1
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(3)
        .NumberFormat = "%3)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 2
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(4)
        .NumberFormat = "(%4)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 3
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(5)
        .NumberFormat = "(%5)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 4
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(6)
        .NumberFormat = "(%6)"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 5
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(7)
        .NumberFormat = "%7."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 6
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(8)
        .NumberFormat = "%8."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.75)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(2)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 7
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(9)
        .NumberFormat = "%9."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(2)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(2.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 8
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
        ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
        DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
End Sub
```

Comment: You state in your question "This is not my exact multilevel list but one of the built-in ones" so this code cannot be what you have tried and is not working. The macro recorder records everything related to an object. You should record the macro operating on your list adding "Text" where you are trying to do it and post that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multilevel list styles use ordinary paragraph styles that are co-ordinated by an overall list style. In use, you do **not** apply the list style to text. Instead you apply one of the paragraph styles.

To start, it's best to learn how to construct a multilevel list style correctly in Word. This will ensure that your styles result in the appearance you expect. Here is Shauna Kelly's method, this works reliably: [How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word 2007 and Word 2010](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768)

If you set up Heading 1 as described in the article, your VBA to apply the style will be:

```
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
```

It's also possible to invoke styles with keyboard shortcuts, so you don't necessarily need to use VBA at all.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I had no idea I could attach the multilevel to a heading. That is so much easier to implement. Thank you.